# tikz style for cell of table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-styles

If I make a table by tikz, I can define style for row or column. For example,

```
\tikzset{
    row 1/.style={
      minimum height=3.5em,
      nodes={font=\bfseries}
    },
    column 1/.style={
      nodes={
        text width=12em,
        font=\bfseries
      }
    },
```

However, how can I just define a style for a specific cell only. Something like

```
    cell (1,1)/.style={
      nodes={fill=gray!10}
    },
```

Comment: You shoud be able to use `row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style is `row ⟨row number⟩ column ⟨column number⟩`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  row 1/.style={
    minimum height=3.5em,
    nodes={font=\bfseries}
  },
  column 1/.style={
    nodes={
      text width=12em,
      font=\bfseries
    }
  },
  row 1 column 1/.style={
    nodes={fill=gray!10}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix{
        \node {1}; & \node{2}; & \node {4}; \\
        \node {4}; & \node{5}; & \node {6}; \\
        \node {7}; & \node{8}; & \node {9}; \\
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On a side note, this is also working on a `matrix of nodes`. You have to load the `matrix` tikz library and this saves you from declaring each cell as a node. I'm not posting another answer below, I assume that you know how to do it.

Comment: The OP did not provide any code as to how their matrix or table looks like, so I just assumed something and used the most simple approach. But of course you are right.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of that. My comment was actually destined to OP.